# Implementing overlapping memmove loop using ARM Neon Intrinsics

Tags: c, optimization, arm, intrinsics, neon

I am new to ARM Neon Intrinsics. I wanted to optimize the below for loop using ARM Neon Intrinsics. I searched on the internet, but I couldn't find any sources.

```
for(i=512;i>0;i--)
     a[i] = a[i-1];

a[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's *needed* to rewrite the loop in assembler yourself? Have you checked the code generated when building with normal compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: So there's no computation, just a `memmove` upward?  (By whatever the type with of `a` is?)  I think normally you'd use `ldp` / `stp` (load/store pair), not unaligned SIMD at all, in asm.  So just let the compiler do that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude..Yes, I want to write using Intrinsics. I am just with checking -O0 optimization. I didn't check with O2/O3 levels

Comment: I would just use `memmove` here. If you turn the optimization levels on the compiler will probably do just that. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yb4rBT
If this is a learning exercise, then I would look into that function's source code for ARM architecture.

Comment: Looking at `-O0` asm output is 100% pointless.  It's always terrible on purpose.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) (applies to GCC and other compilers as well as clang.)

Comment: @JorgeBellon: glibc's memcpy/memmove and some other key functions are hand-written in asm for most ISAs (e.g. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/arm/memmove.S.html for 32-bit ARM, https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/aarch64/memcpy.S.html for AArch64), with a *portable* C fallback for some functions on some (e.g. strlen on MIPS uses the fallback).  glibc never uses C with ISA-specific *intrinsics* so you can't find examples there.  IDK about other C libraries. But yes, just let the compiler optimize this to memmove, or better call it explicitly for better debug-mode perf.

Comment: Is it possible to use VSLI (vector shift left and insert) in this case? The given syntax for VSLI is                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                              
                                   Vop{cond}.size {Qd}, Qm, #imm  .         According to syntax, the size can be 8/16/32/64. Can I use this command in my code to optimize?